# The background task activation is spurious

Tags: microsoft-office

All of my office products popup error messages frequently saying "The background task activation is spurious" and I have to click out of it and it is annoying.

[image: annoying message]

[The Microsoft help page for this problem](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3097938) is audacious enough to list the "Work Around" as 'clicking the ok button.'

Has anyone else encountered this and found an actual solution?

Edit: This is Office 2016

Comment: I've never encountered this before, so I can't help you with this. It does help if you actually edit your post to include which version of office you're using. I bet its not office 2003? Also, is it on one pc only or do more than one have the same problem? Have you tried to repair your office and in worst case reinstall it?

Comment: Clicked the link which states its an issue with Office 2016. So I guess that's what you're using. The link also states that Microsoft is aware of the issue and is attempting to fix it. They may already have done so, so make sure you check for Windows Update, and include updates for non-windows too, which includes office.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook, go to File Tab, Office Account and Sign out. This was enough to solve my problem. I hope it works for you

Answer (score -2):

In Excel (or other Office app), go to the File tab and click account;
Below the user information, click Exit and then enter again.
This was enough to solve my problem.
I hope it works for you.